# Calculate two numbers in jQuery

Tags: jquery

i have problem calculate 2 numbers has comma in jquery or javascript

i take the first and second number from div "attr"

this is my example code

```
var firstnumber = $('.first_price').attr('price'); //its 5,000
var secondnumber = $('.second_price').attr('price'); //its 6,000

$('#total').html( Math.floor(firstnumber+secondnumber) );

//also tried
$('#total').html( Number(firstnumber+secondnumber) );
```

its return 0 , but when i remove the comma from the price its retruen 11000 
how to make it return 11,000 i mean i need it to calculate the two numbers if they has comma any help ?

Comment: There is no attribute named `price` anywhere in any HTML spec. So do not use it. Use `data-price="..."` instead and access it using `.data('price')`

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the comma and then reapply the comma

```
var firstnumber = $('.first_price').data('price');
var secondnumber = $('.second_price').data('price');
firstnumber  = firstnumber.replace(/,/g , '');
secondnumber = secondnumber.replace(/,/g , '');
var result = addCommas(firstnumber+secondnumber);
```

Function to add commas back in

```
function addCommas(nStr){
nStr += '';
x = nStr.split('.');
x1 = x[0];
x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
while (rgx.test(x1)) {
    x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
}
return x1 + x2;
}
```

Comment: You should make sure you're regex does a global replace, this only replaces the first occurence of a comma, so 5,000,000 won't be 5000000, it will be 5000,000

Comment: I fixed the regex in my code to replace all commas in the string

Comment: so the regex in your code will remove all commas from the string now ?

Comment: Yes it should I have not personally tested it but you could add a alert(secondnumber) to make sure.

Comment: I'd recommend this regex `.replace(/[^\d.]/g,'')` instead so it only keeps valid numbers (digits and decimal place), rather than trying to strip out bad characters.

Comment: hmmm so what should i use now .replace(/[^\d.]/g,'') or .replace(/,/g , '') i did use .replace(/,/g , ''); its works so !

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer:

```
var firstnumber = $('.first_price').data('price').replace( /[\$,]/g, '' ) ; 
var secondnumber = $('.second_price').data('price').replace( /[\$,]/g, '' ) ;
var total = Math.floor(firstnumber+secondnumber)
$('#total').html( formatCurrency(total)  );


function formatCurrency( amount ) {
amount = ('' + amount).replace( /[$,]/g, '' );
if( isNaN( amount ))
    amount = '0';

var cents = Math.round( amount * 100 ); // Total number of cents
amount = Math.abs( amount > 0 ? Math.floor(amount) : Math.ceil(amount) ) + ''; // Number of complete dollars

for( var i = 0; i < Math.floor( (amount.length - ( 1 + i )) / 3 ); i++ )
    amount = [amount.substring( 0, amount.length - ( 4 * i + 3 ) ), amount.substring( amount.length - ( 4 * i + 3 ))].join(',');

return (cents >= 0 ? '' : '-') + amount + '.' + (Math.abs(cents) % 100).zeroFill(2);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the strings to numbers:

```
var firstnumber = +$('.first_price').attr('price');
var secondnumber = +$('.second_price').attr('price');
```

However, instead of working with invalid attributes which are just plain strings consider using `data-price="5000"` in your HTML; then the following code will work fine:

```
var firstnumber = $('.first_price').data('price');
var secondnumber = $('.second_price').data('price');
```

Oh, and don't put those thousands separators in your prices. They do not belong into *data* at all; that's a *display* thingy. If you cannot get rid of them you need to convert to int in both cases but remove them first (`.replace(/,/g, '')`)

Answer (score 0):

It's because it's not a number yet, it's a string, remove the commas

```
var firstnumber = $('.first_price').attr('price').replace(/[^\d.]/g,''); //its 5,000
var secondnumber = $('.second_price').attr('price').replace(/[^\d.]/g,''); //its 6,000

$('#total').html( Math.floor(firstnumber+secondnumber) );
```

I changed the regex to only keep valid number values, (digits and decimal place) and remove the rest.  Since these are prices, negative numbers should be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#total').html(  Math.floor(parseInt(firstnumber.replace(',',''),10)+parseInt(secondnumber.replace(',',''),10)) ));
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/73H7B/)**

You need to get rid of the commas before parsing your strings into integers.

Comment: your replace is only removing the first comma, if it's 5,000,000 it won't work

Comment: True, however the OP's example didn't mention 5,000,000. If it did, then I'd have posted a different answer.

Comment: really?  it's a number, support them all.  Which, reminds me, I should tweak my answer to have better support